# Azure: Deployment of application without taking it down (without loosing active users of application)

Tags: azure, deployment, cloud, azure-web-roles

I am using Microsoft Azure cloud Services, I am deploying my local code to production and staging.

I came across one scenario as below:

If production code is in running and some users are active to the application site, now I want to deploy my code without loosing active users (without taking my application down).

**Output that i want:** So my new code will be deployed and active users (Log in users) will be not affected.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you have found an answer to this, the solution to this problem is to have multiple deployments (staging and production) and then swap them when you're ready to promote the staging to production.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-manage/#how-to-swap-deployments-to-promote-a-staged-deployment-to-production